# str_replace() making wrong replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How is this possible that the **str_replace()** function below returns **biWeekly** and not **Every Other Week** ?

```
$payFrequency = "biweekly";
$postData['payFrequency'] = str_replace(array('weekly','biweekly','twicemonthly','monthly'),array('Weekly','Every Other Week','Twice a Month','Monthly'), $payFrequency, $cnt);
echo "$cnt {$postData['payFrequency']}\n"; // SHOWS 1 biWeekly
```

Comment: I updated it; original string is into $payFrequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is case-sensitive, so `biweekly` gets replaced, but `biWeekly` does not. Use [`str_ireplace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) if you want a case-insensitive replace.

Comment: @jeroen sure it does, but it takes two replacements to get the final result. I guess, this solution is wrong in general, i.e. we can find an example where it will work wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should swap first and second items in both arrays.

```
$payFrequency = "biweekly";
$postData['payFrequency'] = str_replace(array('biweekly','weekly','twicemonthly','monthly'),array('Every Other Week','Weekly','Twice a Month','Monthly'), $payFrequency, $cnt);
echo "$cnt {$postData['payFrequency']}\n"; // SHOWS 1 biWeekly
```

this would work.

Answer (score 2):

It replaces the "weekly" in "biweekly" with "Weekly", which afterwards does not match "biweekly" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

because biweekly contains "weekly" which is your first match in the array

```
array('weekly','biweekly','twicemonthly','monthly')
```

Thus it converts that first then return.

You could swap your order of replacements:

```
$payFrequency = "biweekly";

$postData['payFrequency'] = str_replace(
        array('biweekly','weekly','twicemonthly','monthly'), // biweekly then weekly
        array('Every Other Week','Weekly','Twice a Month','Monthly'), $payFrequency, $cnt
);

echo "$cnt {$postData['payFrequency']}\n";
```